# What is the average velocity of an object between time intervals? Using the derivative.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, average

> [image]

Here is my work on this problem so far:

I know to find the average velocity, I should first find the derivative of the height vs time function. 
$$f(t)=80-4.9t^2$$
$$f'(t)=-9.8t+C$$

Where do I go from here to find average velocity? I know the answers to this problem, but am having a hard time figuring out how they are arrived at.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The point of this exercise was to find out (at the very end) the value of $f'(t)$. You jumped ahead to that result. Also, there is no $+C$ term to add to a derivative; you do that only for antiderivatives (aka indefinite integrals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average velocity is simply the distance, covered by the object, divided by the time it took for the object to cover that distance.

There is no need to calculate $f'(t)$ to answer (a,b,c). You only need to calculate $\frac{f(t_1-f(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}$ where $t_0=1$ and $t_1$ takes three different values.

Comment: Okay, I guess I thought that was too easy... So that is the case even though the object is falling?

Comment: @McB That is always the case because that is the definition of average velocity: total distance covered divided by the time it took.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we can directly apply the formula for average velocity ($\bar{v}$).

the average velocity of the object is given as $$\bar{v}=\frac{\text{total distance traveled in time interval}\ \Delta t}{\text{total time required}\ (\Delta t)}$$$$=\frac{f(t_1)-f(t_2)}{t_2-t_1}=\frac{f(t_1)-f(t_2)}{\Delta}$$
Since, the height of the object from the ground is decreasing with the time $(t)$

1. from $t_1=1\ sec$ to $t_2=1.1\ sec$ average velocity is $$=\frac{(80-4.9(1)^2)-(80-4.9(1.1)^2)}{1.1-1}$$ $$=\frac{1.029}{0.1}=\color{red}{10.29}$$
   I hope you can calculate rest of the values